# The finite complement topology on the plane

Tags: general-topology

Is the finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ the same as the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that results from taking the product of two finite complement topology? And why?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this?

Comment: I do, by looking to the basic open sets for each of which but I think that it's not correct way because I lead to a result that the two are same!

Comment: @fatma: If you have tried something, it is a good idea to include this in the original question. Otherwise people will think that you haven't tried anything and that you are just trying to get other people to do your homework.

Comment: All (non-empty) open subsets of the finite complement topology on the plane are of the form  R^2\F, where F subset of the plane that is finite. 
And all (non-empty) open subsets of the finite complement topology on the real line are of the form  R\F_1, where F_1 a finite subset of the first projection . same thing for the second projection

Comment: so its not the same right? I just wanted to clarify, Thank you for the help fatma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ a set $X$ is open if and only if the complement $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus X$ is finite.

In the finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$ a set $Y$ is open if and only if the complement $\mathbb{R} \setminus Y$ is finite.

Answer this question, and you have solve your problem: Let $Y = \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$, so $Y$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $X = Y\times Y$. Is $X$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$? What is the complement of $X$?

Comment: X= {(a,b): a belongs to R∖0, b belongs to R∖0} _


X is not open in R^2

Comment: Many thanks for your time

Comment: excuse me I want to ask why X×X is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2_{fc}$. It seems to me that Y is open so is Y×Y since $\mathbb{R}_{fc} \times \mathbb{R}_{fc}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2_{fc}$"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my thought:
As an example take *A = R-{0}* and *B = R-{2,3}*, as it's clear *A* and *B* are open in $R_{fc}$. Now consider *C = A × B*. The set *C* doesn't contain any pair *(0,y)* in $R^2$ which are infinite number of points in $R^2$. Therefore, the complement of *C* is not finite and consequently, *C* is not open in $R^2_{fc}$.